# Using recent changes with backlinks in MediaWiki API

Tags: perl, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm getting a list of pages using the [`backlinks`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aBacklinks) API query, but I want only those pages which have been edited within a certain time period.  I've tried to do that by using [`recentchanges`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aRecentchanges), but as you will see in the code I'm not getting what I want.

This is the code I'm using:

```perl
my $redir = $medWik->list ( {
    action => 'query',
    list => 'backlinks ', #| recentchanges', #here it cuts everything
    #list => 'recentchanges', # here it froze ther program after 1 loop
    bltitle => $articletitle,
    blredirect, 
    bllimit=> 'max',
    blfilterredir => 'redirects', 
    list => recentchanges, # here it isnt cutting anything.
    rcstart => $StartDate, #previously defined
    rcend => $EndDate, #previously defined
    rcdir => 'newer',
    rctype => 'edit | new | log', 
} )
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the results I want?

Versions:

- MediaWiki 1.17.0
- PHP   5.3.5 (apache2handler)
- MySQL 5.5.8

Comment: What's the API client framework you're using? Is it [MediaWiki::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MediaWiki::API)?

Comment: Anyway, if I understood you correctly, you want something like the output of [Special:RecentChangesLinked](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:RecentChangesLinked), only using the API. I couldn't find any obvious way to achieve that, and I suspect that it may simply be an oversight in the API. If I have some time later, I might try to see how hard it would be to add that feature, although I have to admit I'm not that familiar with the API internals.

Comment: yeah im using MediaWiki::API, and yes like you say i want to find pages that got changed within a time frame, that are linked to/from a specific page, i tried to do the same thing that i did when i got the recent changes pages from a certain category (instead of all), but no luck

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you do it with the category? Do you mean `cmsort=timestamp` or something else?

Comment: i did: my $articles = $medWik->list    <br/>
           ({  action => 'query',      <br/>
        list => 'categorymembers',    
        list    => 'recentchanges',
       cmtitle => 'Category:Published', 
       cmlimit => 'max',
      #To specify the search:
      rcstart => $StartDate,
      rcend => $EndDate,
      rcdir => 'newer',
      rctype  => 'edit  | new | log',      

     } )

Comment: wops forgot to add, that code returns the files edited with in a certain time constrain, that belong to a certain category (in this case published)

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it, I used 2 methods instead of 1, with backlinks I got the pages name and with that I searched with those names to get the date, some `for` and `if`'s later I get the pages I want.